# Creating a charAt() method

Tags: java

Part of my assignment is to create a `charAt()` method that will return the char value at the specified index. If the index if invalid, it will return the character at index zero.

This is what I have so far, keep in mind that my assignment specifically states I cannot use existing string methods for Java.

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    char a;
    if (index < 0 || index > 25)
      a = list[0];
    else
      a = list[index];
    return a;
}
```

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` error whenever I go to call the method `charAt`. Are there any corrections or pointers that you recommend? Or is the question too vague?

Comment: Where have u defined list? Most likely it is null.

Comment: You may consider looking at the Java library method for ideas. Don't copy it, of course, but it should provide some insight and give you some exposure to libraries.

Comment: The nullPointerException should give you the exact line number where it is occurring. Also where is the number '25' coming from? Is that the maximum size? What if the list[] array is smaller than 25? What is list[] has not been allocated?

Comment: Yes, I believe I didn't post the actual problem. I do indeed define list earlier in my code and 25 is the maximum size. I made sure to account for if list[]array is smaller than 25. I checked where exactly the nullPointerException error is coming from and it is in my toString() method.

Comment: ..then why are you posting the `charAt` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account the actual data you are using, rather than using a "Magic Number" for your bounds check:

```
if (list.length == 0) {
    //error, no data
}
char back = list[0];
if (index >= 0 && index < data.length) {
    back = list[index];
}
return back;
```

On another note, as Juned pointed out in the comments, if you have null values and attempt to dereference them (via the `.` or `[]`), you will get a `NullPointerException`.

So some possible causes would be:

- `list` is null
- The object you are calling `charAt` for is null, e.g. `myData` being null in `myData.charAt(42)`